# PLSQL oracle - what's more performant? NVL() or IS NULL?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, database-migration

I need to migrate 4 millions of records.

In the validator, to check if a column is NULL, what's more performant?

```
WHERE name IS NULL;
```

or

```
WHERE NVL(name,' ') = ' '
```

Comment: Both are filter predicates, however 2nd one does need an extra function to call for each row.

Comment: Note that these filter predicates are not equivalent - the second one will count names that are already a single space `' '`.

Comment: Also, we are assuming that `name` is a VARCHAR2.

Answer (score 0):

On my machine for a table with 3689150 rows:

```
create table t234 as
select editionable as name
from all_objects
cross join (
  select 1 from dual
  connect by level <= 50
);
select count(*) from t234;

  COUNT(*)
----------
   3689150
```

the first one is much more faster:

```
set timing on
select count(*) from t234 where name is null;

  COUNT(*)
----------
   1612400

Elapsed: 00:00:00.094
```

---

```
select count(*) from t234 where NVL(name,' ') = ' ';

  COUNT(*)
----------
   1612400

Elapsed: 00:00:00.203
```

The first query takes 94 miliseconds, the second one 203 miliseconds, 
so the first one is over 100% faster - you will save over 100 miliseconds using `NOT NULL` operator instead of `NVL(name,' ') = ' '`

Comment: This may be true; but it might not be. A single wall-clock comparison like this is nowhere near enough evidence to support your conclusion. A 2x performance difference for something that only takes about 200 milliseconds anyway is not very compelling (call me if you see a 10x improvement). Try running this 10,000 times, in both orders (A followed by B, and B followed by A) and then see if the difference in performance is actually significant or not. Also, there are many factors you have not specified, e.g. what sort of machine is this running on, disk speed, current state of the buffer cache..

Comment: Also, the optimiser has some idea of how many rows are null based on the `num_nulls` statistic for the column, but it won't know how many match some arbitrary `nvl()` expression. This may make a difference in a more complex query involving joins etc. It may apply a rule of thumb (e.g. _'any function result will match 5% of rows'_) and you could be lucky or unlucky with the resulting join order.